# If the altitude of the aircraft is given by the pitot tube, in icing condition with heat on, how is real altitude /speed interpretation done?

Tags: flight-instruments, airspeed, pitot-static, measurement

If the altitude  of the aircraft is given by the pitot tube, in icing condition with pitot heat on how is  real altitude /speed interpretation done? Because the air density and temperature is not realistic, due to the fact that pitot tube is hot .

Comment: The pitot tube is used for airspeed, not altitude measurement.

Comment: No, because I asked about altitude not relative speed. WHAT instrument do that?

Comment: @GeorgeGeo You asked about a heated pitot tube, which is answered in the linked duplicate. Altitude is derived from static pressure, which is usually measured by a static port, which is *not* heated. The two functions can be combined (see [What is the difference between a pitot tube and a pitot-static tube?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38468/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pitot-tube-and-a-pitot-static-tube)), but that does not change the validity of the answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The pitot tube measures pressure, not density. The pressure is not affected by the heating of the tube.

Comment: Would it be affected by viscosity? And would viscosity be affected by temperature?

Comment: @Bianfable: I cannot quantity the effect, so my question, it should be more important [at low velocity](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1976IzMZG..12..136M/abstract) since the inertia effect will be lower (the linked article is not accessible).

Comment: @mins Interesting, thanks for the link. It's probably a small effect (since viscosity is increasing [less than linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Air) with temperature), but it might make for an interesting new question.